# Why UISearchBar does not get Focus even after it is set as a first responder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, becomefirstresponder

Why UISearchBar does not get Focus and keyboard does not appear when UIViewController is pushed to navigation controller for the 2nd time? It seems as no element on the whole view has a focus.

**MY USE CASE**: I have 2 View Controllers: A and B. Transition is A->B. A, B are pushed to navigation controller.

1. When I show B ***for the first time focus is set*** to the searchbar and keyboard appears.OK.
2. Then I go back to the A. And again from A->B. Now ***for the second time*** there is ***no focus*** and ***keyboard does not appear***. It is WRONG.

**MY CODE**: On the B UIViewController IBOutlet connection to the searchbar is created:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *mySearchBar;
```

Delegate of the mySearchBar is also set.
I set focus on the searchbar in B UIViewController in `viewDidAppear` method:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];   
    [self performSelector:@selector(setCorrectFocus) withObject:NULL afterDelay:0.2];
}

-(void) setCorrectFocus {
     [self.mySearchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Transitions between controllers are done manually in code like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"myStoryboard" bundle:nil];
AController *a = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"A"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:a animated:NO];
```

Comment: I tried you code, and it worked fine for me, so the problem is not in your posted code. Is setCorrectFocus called the second time you go from A to B? Also, how are you doing the transitions from A to B, and back again? In code? With segues?

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying. Strange I thought I commented out everything in my code except these posted things. No not with segues, manually in code.

Comment: It might have something to do with the way the controllers are set up, or the way the transitions are done -- it's hard to diagnose these kinds of things without actually seeing the app.

Comment: Could I may be see your example of code, if it is possible? How have you done it, that by you it works?

Comment: There's no code to see other than what you posted. I added two controllers in a storyboard embedded in a navigation controller. I put a button in the first one connected to a push segue to go to the second one (which had the code you posted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After long searching I found Error. Somewhere in storyboard old connection for UISearchBar with the name mySearchbar was left. Another thing that I had to correct was that the method

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar;
```

returned `NO`, every time I went back to previous Controller. But it should return `YES` to be able to set focus on search bar next time.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];   
     [self setCorrectFocus];
}

-(void)setCorrectFocus 
{
     [self.mySearchBar becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Was strugling with the same - had a UISearchBar inside a UITextView's keyboard accessory and even after `[self.searchBar becomeFirstResponder]` was called, keyboard input was still received by the text view.

This is what finally helped:

```
[self.searchBar.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Apparently the keyboard accessory is part of a different UIWindow than the UITextField.

Note: To continue typing in the text view, you should then call something like `[self.textView.window makeKeyAndVisible];` ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `self.mySearchBar.delegate = self;`

Answer (score -1):

You should use strong in your property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *mySearchBar;
```

Always set strong in your property for IBOutlet. When you pop B from navigationController, mySearchBar has released, so you push back to B, [self.mySearchBar becomeFirstResponder] is not work.

Comment: IBOutlets are generally `weak` because the view controller already has a strong reference to the subview by way of the top-level view